# extrema of funcion

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

$f(x,y,z)=x+2z$ and $M=\{[x,y,z]\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+2y^2=4,z+y\le 1\}$. I found out that M is not bounded from below so it does not have minimum or infimum. But how do I find maximum? I tried to use lagrange multipler and got:
$\nabla f-\lambda \nabla$g=0,where $g(x,y,z)]=x^2+2y^2-4$
$$1-\lambda2x=0$$
$$0-\lambda4y=0$$
$$2-\lambda \cdot 0=0$$
I am stuck here, the third equation is obviously wrong. So how do I continue?

Comment: Looks like you tried single constraint Lagrange, but what about the $z+y\le 1$ constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As coffeemath noted in the comments, you're actually given (and would have to account for) two constraints here to jump into applying Lagrange multipliers directly. An example of how to do this can be found [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LagrangeMultipliers.aspx) towards the end of the page. So, instead of just following along the usual algorithm, I thought I'd show you how a little bit of thinking about the functions in this case allows you to reduce the problem to maximizing a two variable function $f_1(x,y)$ subject to a single constraint.

Note that for a fixed $x,y$ with $x^2 + 2y^2 = 4$, if $z_1 < z_2$ then $f(x,y,z_1) < f(x,y,z_2)$. So $F(z) = f(x,y,z)$, for fixed $x$ and $y$ satisfying the constraint, is maximized when $z$ is as large as possible while remaining in $M$, *i.e.*, for $z = 1-y$. So really you may view $f$ as a function of two variables $f_1(x,y) = x + 2(1-y) = x + 2 - 2y$, and maximizing $f$ on $M$ is the same as maximizing maximize $f_1$ on the set $M_1 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + 2y^2 = 4\}$. Let $g_1(x,y) = x^2 + 2y^2 - 4$. Then $\nabla f_1(x,y) - \lambda\nabla g_1(x,y) = \langle 0,0\rangle$ together with our constraint says that
\begin{align}
    1 - 2\lambda x &= 0,\\
   -2 - 4\lambda y &= 0, \text{ and}\\
    x^2 + 2y^2 &= 4.
\end{align}
The first and second equations tell us that $x,y,\lambda \neq 0$, $x = 1/(2\lambda)$, and $y = -1/(2\lambda)$. So from the last equation
\begin{align}
    4 &= x^2 + 2y^2 = \frac{1}{4\lambda^2} + \frac{2}{4\lambda ^2}\\
\implies \lambda^2 &= \frac{3}{16} \implies \lambda \in \left\{\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right\}.
\end{align}
Therefore $f_1$ is maximized at some $(x,y) \in \{(\pm 2/\sqrt3, \mp 2/\sqrt3)\}$. We check $f_1(\pm 2/\sqrt3, \mp 2/\sqrt3) = \pm4/3 \pm8/3 + 2$ attains a larger value at $(2/\sqrt3,-2/\sqrt3)$ than $(-2/\sqrt3,2/\sqrt3)$, and so $f$ is maximized on $M$ at $(x,y,z) = (x,y,1-y) = (2/\sqrt3,-2/\sqrt3,1+2/\sqrt3)$.

Comment: I am sorry for replying late, thank you for detailed answer I think it is much clearer to me now. I had a typo, in the constraint it should have been $z+y^2\le1$. But at least I could compute it using what I learned from you. So I found two points instead $[2,0,1]$ and $[−1/2,\sqrt{15/8},−7/8]$, I have just small question regarding this, even if I solve it for M1 it still has to satisfy conditions in original set M right? So if hypothetically $[−1/2,\sqrt{15/8},−7/8] \not \in M$ I wouldn't even need to plug in to see if it has a greater value than $[2,0,1]$?

Comment: I have one additional question(hope you don't mid): In the link you provided, there are two constraints that are set equal to $0$, but my second constraint is not given as equality but inequality $\le$ so if I wanted to use that "mechanical" approach. How would I do that (another link would suffice I think, I am not native speaker, so it is kind of hard for me to formulate queries correctly for google to find what I want)

Comment: @D.N: Great questions! I'm happy things are clearer to you now. `:)` Regarding your first comment, yes, if you found a point that solved a simplified form of the problem but didn't satisfy your original constraints (*e.g.*, wasn't in $M$ in this case) then you can safely remove that point from your considerations. Of course, this wouldn't occur in the above solution, since the points in $M_1$ you solve for must (a) satisfy $z + y = 1$ (or $z+y^2 = 1$ with the corrected constraint) and also a system of equations which includes the other constraint $x^2 + 2y^2 = 4$.

Comment: @D.N: Regarding your second question, I don't have an example at the ready with two constraints that are both inequalities. In general, though, the idea is the same as when there is only one inequality. Namely you first identify all critical points of the function $f$ you're trying to optimize, ignoring any that don't satisfy the inequalities. Then you treat them as equalities and use Lagrange multipliers to identify possible extrema on the boundary of the domain $M$ you're optimizing over and proceed by comparing the values of $f$ at all of these points. (This is like in ... (ct'd)

Comment: ... single variable calculus when you identify extrema of a function on an interval $[a,b]$ by first identifying possible extreme on $(a,b)$ *via* differentiation and then comparing the values of your function at those points as well as at $a$ and $b$ ($a$ and $b$ comprising the boundary of $[a,b]$). The only difference now is that we have to deal with the fact that we have infinitely many values on the boundary of $M$ (and hence can't just check them one-by-one), and that's where Lagrange multipliers come in handy.

Comment: Alright, I see. Thank you once again, you have helped me a lot, I really appreciate how you gave me thorough explanation :)

Comment: @D.N: My pleasure! Happy to help! `:)`